# How to use PyQt5 without a Virtual Environment

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I recently tried to make an PyQt5 Web Browser. It kept on showing errors until I used a virtual environment to run the code. Now I want to run the code WITHOUT a virtual environment, but it just displays this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Browser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module could not be found.
```

My code looks like this:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 
web = QWebEngineView()
web.load(QUrl(url))
web.setZoomFactor(2)
web.zoomFactor()
web.show()
 
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Just so you know, I use Windows 10 (64 bit) and Python 3.8.5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to run a complex Python application that requires one or several third party packages without a virtual environment. Initially it may seem easier, but it will end up getting a mess and when you start another project, it may end up in countless conflicts. So, take the time to understand the basics of virtual environments, starting with the official method that comes with the Python Standard Library. You can lear more about it here:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

### 1. Create a new virtual environment in the current folder, putting everything needed inside a subfolder named "venv":

```
C:> python3.8 -m venv venv
```

### 2. Activate the virtual environment:

#### A. using cmd

```
C:> venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

#### B. using PowerShell

```
C:> venv\Scripts\Activate.ps1
```

#### C: in macOS or Linux:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
```

### 3. Install third party packages

```
$ python3.8 -m  pip install PACKAGE_NAME
```

Then you can edit and run the application, and it will use those packages, with the specific versions you have installed (which may be different from the ones you have used in other projects in the same system.

### 4. Deactivate the virtual environment

When you're done and want to leave the virtual environment, you just need to type the following command:

```
C:> deactivate
```

But if you are building such an application sooner or later you will need to package the application and add a setup.py file that will make possible to install it with pip and, who knows, even distribute it for other users in PyPI.org, in case that's your intention.

Start by looking here:

https://packaging.python.org/guides/

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I really need to automate everything. I tried somethings that worked, so I happy with my results.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I could just turn my python file into an exe file. I used Pyinstaller like this:

`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole Browser.py`

And it WORKED! So, if anyone wants to try that, be my guest. Just make sure you do it in your virtual environment, or else I can't guarantee success. You also need to download Pyinstaller inside the virtual environment.

**Warning:** The EXE Application only works if it is one file, and it also loads very slow. Remember to keep that in mind when running the Application!